# not retrieving all the objects while deserializing a file

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

Serializing data through

```
try {
  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(
      "C:\\Users\\saikiran\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\FTP\\reg.ser", true);
  ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
  out.writeObject(r);
  out.close();
  fileOut.close();
  System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /tmp/reg.ser");
  pr.println("Registered Successfully ");
} catch (IOException i) {
  i.printStackTrace();
}
```

and while  Deserializing not getting entire file objects only getting single object i.e starting object only .

```
 FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\saikiran\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\FTP\\reg.ser");
                   ObjectInputStream in = null;                       
while (fileIn.available() != 0) {

  in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
  while (in != null && in.available() != 0) {
    r = (Registration) in.readObject();
    System.out.println("Logged in :" + "User name :" + r.u + "Password  " + r.p);

    if (r.u.equals(ur) && r.p.equals(ps)) {
      System.out.println("Logged in :" + "User name :" + r.u + "Password  " + r.p);
      pr.println("Display");

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `fileIn`, what is `in`? Why do you reassign `in` when entering the outer `while` loop?

Comment: r.u and r.p are null?

Comment: Your first code snippet only serializes a single object. Where do you expect the other objects to come from? AFAIK repeatedly serializing into separate `ObjectOutputStream`s will not allow you to read multiple objects with a single `ObjectInputStream`. Either write out all your objects with a single `ObjectOutputStream` (and multiple calls to `writeObject()`), or read them with several separate `ObjectInputStream`s.

Comment: Why two checks while(in.available() != 0)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379912/how-to-deserialize-object

Comment: above link is not working

Comment: Do you have multiple objects in single file?

Comment: yes every time while executing new objecting is saving in to the file appending at the end of file

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know for help.

Answer (score 0):

**I have created the working sample for you .**

My `POJO serializable` class will be ,

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Pojo implements Serializable{

    String name;
    String age;
    String qualification;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getQualification() {
        return qualification;
    }
    public void setQualification(String qualification) {
        this.qualification = qualification;
    }

}
```

My `main` class will be,

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Serialization {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static final String FILENAME = "F:\\test\\cool_file.ser";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {


        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        //ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(FILENAME);
            //oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
/*          for (String s : test.split("\\s+")) {
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(s);
            }*/

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
                pojo.setName("HumanBeing - "+i);
                pojo.setAge("25 - "+i);
                pojo.setQualification("B.E - "+i);
                oos.writeObject(pojo);
            }

        } finally {
            if (fos != null)
                fos.close();
        }

        List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        //ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(FILENAME);
            //ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            while (true) {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                results.add(ois.readObject());
            }
        } catch (EOFException ignored) {
            // as expected
        } finally {
            if (fis != null)
                fis.close();
        }
        System.out.println("results = " + results);

        for (int i=0; i<results.size()-1; i++) {
            System.out.println(((Pojo)results.get(i)).getName()+ "    "+((Pojo)results.get(i)).getAge()+ "    "+((Pojo)results.get(i)).getQualification());
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this helped or not?